# Finding out a limit using Taylor series.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

So the limit is the following:

$$\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{x^2-\frac{x^6}{2}-x^2 \cos (x^2)}{\sin (x^{10})}}$$

Expansions for $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ are given:

$$\sin x = x-\frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!}-...+(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!} + o(x^{2n})$$ 
$$\cos x = 1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-...+(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}+o(x^{2n+1})$$

Here is what I tried:
$$\lim_{x->0}{\frac{x^2-\frac{x^6}{2}-x^2(1-\frac{x^4}{2}+\frac{x^8}{4!}+o(x^{2*5}))}{x^{10}+o(x^{10*2})}}=\lim_{x->0}{\frac{-\frac{x^{10}}{4!}-o(x^{12})}{x^{10}+o(x^{20})}}$$

This is where I am stuck. I figured that the problem occurs when expending $o()$. What am I missing here?

Comment: Also better to use \sin than just sin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about factoring by $x^{10}$?

Comment: What does $o(x^{20})/x^{10}$ tend to?

Comment: $\frac{o(x^m)}{x^n} $ tends to $0$ in $0$ for $m \geq n \in \mathbb{N}$. Go back to the definition of $o$ to see it

Answer (score 5):

The numerator is 
$$x^2-\frac{x^6}2-x^2\Bigl(1-\frac{x^4}2+\frac{x^8}{24}+o(x^8)\Bigr)=-\frac{x^{10}}{24}+o(x^{10}),$$
hence
$$\frac{x^2-\cfrac{x^6}{2}-x^2 \cos (x^2)}{\sin (x^{10})}\sim_0\frac{-\dfrac{x^{10}}{24}}{x^{10}}=-\frac1{24}.$$

*Editors Note: Sorry, can't leave comments yet. When you factor in the $-x^2$ you'll end with $-\frac{1}{24}$.

Comment: Sure, but where is there a term in $\frac1{x^4}$?

Comment: My apologies, I got the term incorrect

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to note that $\frac{\sin x^{10}}{x^{10}} \to_x 1$, so you get your $x^{10}$ in the denominator.

Comment: The problem still remains in numerator. $o(x^{12})/x^{10}$ doesn't give anything, right?

Comment: $\frac{x^{12}}{x^{10}} = x^2 \to 0$

Comment: Oh god, completely missed that $x->0$... Thanks for help and sorry for wasting your time :)

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2-\frac{x^6}{2}-x^2\cos(x^2)}{\sin(x^{10})} = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2-\frac{x^6}{2}-x^2(1-\frac{x^4}{2}+\frac{x^8}{24}-\frac{x^{12}}{720}+\cdots)}{x^{10}-\frac{x^{30}}{6}+\cdots}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2-\frac{x^6}{2}+(-x^2+\frac{x^6}{2}-\frac{x^{10}}{24}+\frac{x^{12}}{720}-\cdots)}{x^{10}-\frac{x^{30}}{6}+\cdots}$$

Canceling terms in the numerator simplifies the equation to:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-\frac{x^{10}}{24}+\cdots}{x^{10}-\cdots}$$

The other terms in the series are unnecessary, so

$$\lim_{x\to0}(-\frac{x^{10}}{24}*\frac{1}{x^{10}}) = -\frac{1}{24}$$