# How to demonstrate the existence of this limit

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

The question is to find the limit of the following function in $ \mathbb{R}^2$ for $(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)$

$$
f(x,y)=\frac{\sin(x)\sin(y)}{\sin(xy)}
$$

I don't know how to demonstrate it. I know that if the limit exists it is equal to one.
Because of
$$
f(x,x)=\frac{\sin(x)\sin(x)}{\sin(x^2)} \sim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2}{x^2}=1
$$

Comment: The approach here might be useful https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1760199/finding-out-a-limit-using-taylor-series

Comment: I assume you are asking for x. y -> 0.  sin(xy) ~ xy, etc.

Comment: Note: $$\frac{\sin(x)\sin(y)}{\sin(xy)}=\frac{\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\times\frac{\sin(y)}{y}}{\frac{\sin(xy)}{xy}}$$

Comment: @herbsteinberg Yeah as (x,y) approaches (0,0). But I don't know how to reason sin(xy) -> xy for (x,y)->(0,0). x and y are two different values. I thought it is not possible to make use of the asymptote when you have different variables. Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: @MatthewH. did you just add XY to both numerator and denominator right? :) 
I get that, but I am still unsure about the denominator. How to reason the usage of the asymptote of sine in case of multiple variables.

Comment: @RishiSonthalia thanks for the link, but I want to see a solution without the Taylor expansion if possible.

Comment: $\frac{\sin(\alpha)}{\alpha}\mapsto 1$ as $\alpha\mapsto 0$. Now note $x,y,$ and $xy$ all approach $0$ as $(x,y)\mapsto(0,0)$.

Comment: @MatthewH. Ohh I think I get it. I confused it with another exercise. 
Could you make it an answer? I will accept it. Thanks

Comment: @Harry if $0<xy$ then $xy-\frac{(xy)^3}{6} \lt \sin(xy) \lt xy$,  while if $0>xy$ then $xy-\frac{(xy)^3}{6} \gt \sin(xy) \gt xy$,

Answer (score 1):

In order to demonstrate the limit, we proceed as follows:

$$
f(x,y)=\frac{\sin(x)\sin(y)}{\sin(xy)}
$$

Knowing that
$$
|\sin{x}|<|x|
$$

$$
|f(x,y)| \le \big|\frac{x\cdot{y}}{\sin(xy)}\big|
$$

From which we can recognize the following known limit:

$$
\frac{\sin(xy)}{x\cdot{y}}\sim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{xy}{xy}=1
$$

The solution follows:

$$
|f(x,y)| \le \big|\frac{x\cdot{y}}{\sin(xy)}\big|=1
$$

The limit is 1 by the Squeeze theorem.